# How do I use the OR statement in a Propel query using Symfony

Tags: symfony1, propel

Right now the code below looks for the author_id and the target_object_id in the database and requires both to match, to be retreived by the query. I would like it to be `WHERE author_id='x' || target_object_id='y'` instead of it being && by default, which is what the code below does.

I've looked on Propel and the Symfony manuals, and they don't help me.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add("type", GVCCommentPeer::TYPE_PRIVATE_MESSAGE);
$c->add("author_id", $this->myprofileid);
$c->add("target_object_id", $this->profile->getId());
```

Comment: You can use this site to turn queries into Propel objects: http://propel.jondh.me.uk/criteria/analyse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Criterion objects from your Criteria object and merge them on the condition you require:

```
//create your Criteria
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add("type", GVCCommentPeer::TYPE_PRIVATE_MESSAGE);

//create 2 Criterion objects
$c1 = $c->getNewCriterion("author_id", $this->myprofileid);
$c2 = $c->getNewCriterion("target_object_id", $this->profile->getId());

// merge the two fields on OR
$c1->addOr($c2);

//bind
$c->add($c1);

$result = YOURPEERHEREPeer::doSelect($c);
```